# xsbt-web-plugin how to stop container without killing sbt console

Tags: sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I am using `xsbt-web-plugin` v4.0.1. After starting the `sbt` console, the `tomcat:start` command works fine. However I don't know how to run `tomcat:stop`. When I press `Ctrl-C`, I exit out of console, but I think tomcat continues to run in background. When I press `Ctrl-D`, I see the message `waiting for server to shutdown` and then `sbt` exists. Either case, I am forced to start `sbt` console again.

I have added following 2 lines in `build.sbt`

```
fork in run := true
connectInput in run := true
```

and this line in my `global.sbt`

```
cancelable in Global := true
```

How can I start and stop container without exiting sbt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `tomcat:start`, you can run `tomcat:stop` (or any other sbt command) at any time.

The `tomcat:start` command does not block further interaction with the sbt prompt.  It can be misleading to see the output of the container mixed in with that of the sbt prompt.

The `fork in run`, `connectInput in run`, and `cancelable in Global` settings are not needed to be able to use `tomcat:start` and `tomcat:stop`.

Comment: Thanks @earldouglas. You are right. I got confused after seeing the container output. I didn't release I can enter commands even if the sbt console is showing continuous output. Good to know that I don't need any of those extra `build.sbt` settings to make it work.